Help with a limit calculus problem $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+z)}{n!n^{z-1}} = 1$
I am trying to prove that:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\Gamma(n+z)}{n!n^{z-1}} = 1 $$
I started  Stirling's approximation:
$$ \Gamma(n) \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n $$
I also used Stirling's approximation for $\Gamma(n+z)$:
$$ \Gamma(n+z) \sim \sqrt{2\pi(n+z)}\left(\frac{n+z}{e}\right)^{n+z} $$
And the basic definition that $n! = \Gamma(n+1)$:
$$ n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n $$
Substituting these into the original:
$$  \frac{\sqrt{2\pi(n+z)}\left(\frac{n+z}{e}\right)^{n+z}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n n^{z-1}} $$
$$=  \sqrt{\frac{n+z}{n}}\left(\frac{n+z}{n}\right)^n\left(\frac{n+z}{e}\right)^z\frac{1}{n^{z-1}} $$
Here is where I am stuck.


the first limit is straightforward:
$$ \sqrt{\frac{n+z}{n}} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{z}{n}} $$
As $n \to \infty$, $\frac{z}{n} \to 0$, so:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{1 + \frac{z}{n}} = \sqrt{1 + 0} = 1 $$

the second limit is a basic calculus definition:


$$ \left(\frac{n+z}{n}\right)^n = \left(1 + \frac{z}{n}\right)^n $$
i.e.  $\left(1 + \frac{a}{n}\right)^n$ where $a = z$
thus: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{a}{n}\right)^n = e^a$
Therefore:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{z}{n}\right)^n = e^z $$

Third limit:
$$ \left(\frac{n+z}{e}\right)^z = \frac{n^z}{e^z}\left(1 + \frac{z}{n}\right)^z $$
As $n \to \infty$:


$\left(1 + \frac{z}{n}\right)^z \to 1$ (since $\frac{z}{n} \to 0$)
Therefore:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n+z}{e}\right)^z = \frac{n^z}{e^z} $$


Fourth limit: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{z-1}}$
$$ \frac{1}{n^{z-1}} = n^{-(z-1)} = \frac{1}{n^z} \cdot n $$

When I multiply all these limits together:
$$ 1 \cdot e^z \cdot \frac{n^z}{e^z} \cdot \frac{n}{n^z} = n $$
This does not equal to $1$
Can someone please help me?

For one, Stirling's approximation is
$$
n! = \Gamma(n+1) \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left( \frac n e \right)^n
$$
so the mis-indexing may explain the problems.

It should be $\Gamma(n+z) \sim \sqrt{2\pi(n+z-1)}((n+z-1)/e)^{n+z-1}$. Your asymptotic for $n! $ is correct.

When you compute the limit of $\left(\frac{n+z}{e}\right)^z$ as $n$ goes to $+\infty$, there shouldn't be $n$ on the left hand side...

I will fix your solution. First, $\Gamma(n + z) \sim \sqrt{2\pi(n+z-1)} ((n+z-1)/e)^{n + z - 1}$ and $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n$ by Stirling's Formula. Therefore
$$\frac{\Gamma(n + z)}{n!} \sim \sqrt{\frac{n+z-1}{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{e^{z-1}} \cdot \frac{(n+z-1)^{n+z - 1}}{n^n},$$
hence
\begin{align}\frac{\Gamma(n + z)}{n! n^{z-1}} &\sim \sqrt{\frac{n+z-1}{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{e^{z-1}} \cdot \left(\frac{n + z - 1}{n}\right)^{n + z - 1} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{n+z-1}{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{e^{z-1}} \cdot \left(1 + \frac{z - 1}{n}\right)^{n} \cdot \left(\frac{n + z - 1}{n}\right)^{z - 1}.
\end{align}
As you know $\sqrt{(n+z-1)/n} \to 1$ and $(1 + (z-1)/n)^n \to e^{z - 1}$. As Kolakoski commented, you need to do the third and fourth limits together, to get $((n+z-1)/n)^{z -1} \to 1^{z-1} = 1$. Therefore
$$\frac{\Gamma(n + z)}{n! n^{z-1}} \to 1 \cdot \frac{1}{e^{z-1}} \cdot e^{z-1} \cdot 1 = 1.$$

You can do this more easily using Gautaschi's inequality.
It states that:
$$x^{1-s} \leq \dfrac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+s)} \leq (x+1)^{1-s}$$
$$\iff ( x+1)^{s-1} \leq \dfrac{\Gamma(x+s)}{\Gamma(x+1)} \leq x^{s-1}$$
Or you can write it as:$$( n+1)^{z-1} \leq \dfrac{\Gamma(n+z)}{\Gamma(n+1)} \leq n^{z-1}$$
Divide by $n^{z-1}$ on all sides to get:
$$\left(1+\dfrac1n \right)^{z-1} \leq \dfrac{\Gamma(n+z)}{\Gamma(n+1)\cdot n^{z-1}} \leq 1$$
Which is nothing but
$$\left(1+\dfrac1n \right)^{z-1} \leq \dfrac{\Gamma(n+z)}{n!\cdot n^{z-1}} \leq 1$$
Now, as $n\rightarrow \infty,$ $\left(1+\dfrac1n \right)^{z-1}\rightarrow 1$, so by the Squeeze theorem, the target expression equals $1 \square$
